# php DomXPath - how to get image in current node only and not in child nodes?

Tags: php, domxpath

i need to get only image that in current node and not in child nodes
i want to get only `green/yellow/red/black` images without `not_important.gif` image
i can use query `'.//table/tr/td/img'`
but i need it inside loop

```
<?php
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $html='
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <span>
                            <img src="not_important.gif" />
                        </span>
                        <img src="green.gif" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>yellow</span>
                        <img src="yellow.gif" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>red</span>
                        <img src="red.gif" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>
                            <img src="not_important.gif" />
                        </span>
                        <img src="black.gif" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        ';
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $query = $xpath->query('.//table/tr/td');
        for( $x=0,$results=''; $x<$query->length; $x++ )
        {
            $x1=$x+1;

            $image = $query->item($x)->getELementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');

            $results .= "image $x1 is : $image<br/>";
        }
        echo $results;
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
?>
```

can i do it through `$query->item()->`
i tried `has_attributes` and `getElementsByTagNameNS` and `getElementById`
but i failed ::

Comment: It is Unclear why @Phil's answer is not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
$image = $query->item($x)->getELementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

...with:

```
$td = $query->item($x); // grab the td element
$img = $xpath->query('./img',$td)->item(0); // grab the first direct img child element
$image = $img->getAttribute('src'); // grab the source of the image
```

In other words, use the `XPath` object again to query, but now for `./img`, relative to the context node you provide as the second argument to `query()`. The context node being one of the elements (`td`) of the earlier result.

Answer (score 1):

The query `//table/tr/td/img` should work just fine as the unwanted images all reside in `<span>` elements.

Your loop would look like

```
$images = $xpath->query('//table/tr/td/img');
$results = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $images->length; $i++) {
    $results .= sprintf('image %d is: %s<br />',
                        $i + 1,
                        $images->item($i)->getAttribute('src'));
}
```

Comment: hi Phil, yes i knew but some times i need to get images src and other nodes attribute and values and make some conditionals . something like that ..  so i need it inside loop ..

Comment: @aldr Then update your question accordingly with some examples, we aren't mind readers

Comment: you are right, but i already said that i need it inside loop +1 ::

Comment: @aldr And my answer does indeed include a loop. You'll have to add more detail about what you actually want. FYI, I think fireeyedboy's answer is closer to what you want